How to disable gperftool profiling in python
I want to do CPU profiling with gperftools by setting LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprofiler.so.0 CPUPROFILE=/tmp/myprofile.out.
It works fine on purely C++ environment, but gperftools doesn't work with python, which generates an empty file.
In my environment, the call chain looks like (hard to change due to a few constraints):

executor program -> python program -> C++ subprocess
or, executor program -> C++ program

All programs are launched via an executor program via subprocess.Popen, it's impossible to tell whether the program to execute is python or C++.
To make things worse, python program spawn its own subprocess (C++) and pass down the env variables.
The result is: both python and C++ process dumps profile to the same location, likely the profile ends up with an empty file due to race.
Both python and C++ program have a internal main function (which makes up a few internal setups), I tried unset the env in python main function, but profile file is still generated by python.
My question is: is there a way to uniformly enable CPU profiling via LD_PRELOAD and CPUPROFILE for all C++ processes, but not python ones?

IMHO the simplest approach is to have LD_PRELOAD and CPUPROFILE set just for C++ subprocess. Not really Python guy, but there might be a way there as part of Popen. Or you can simply do shell/python wrapper around C++ subprocess that will set environment variables and exec the real thing.

You can also force creating profile file with pid appended. https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/blob/825b6638cf76aecc5a540d3fa662d157760fc11e/src/base/sysinfo.cc#L333

Hi @AliakseiKandratsenka I agree with you, I think the difficulty comes from the current proj/codebase setup, which is hard to inject env ONLY for C++ subprocesses unfortunately :-(

Well, my point is, doing shell wrapper is the easiest way to achieve what you need. If you don't want or can't do shell wrapper, well, you can have C++ program set environment variables and re-exec itself too.
